# How do I send the Firebase Custom Authentication generated token from Heroku to my client?

Tags: android, heroku, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin

I'm trying to implement custom authentication for Android in my app.

The form I want is a phone number only. Currently I'm doing this:

- I have an application using heroku in IntelliJ that generates the custom token.
- I deployed that app to Heroku.

The problem I'm facing is that I **am** running the Java application in Heroku. However, all I have right now is:

```
String uid = "some-uid";
HashMap<String, Object> additionalClaims = new HashMap<String, Object>();
additionalClaims.put("premiumAccount", true);

FirebaseAuth.getInstance().createCustomToken(uid, additionalClaims)
    .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(String customToken) {
            // Send token back to client
        }
    });
```

What I'm confused about:

1. How do I communicate from the Android client with the server running in Heroku?
2. How do I get the token which I generated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to see up a web framework like [Spark](http://sparkjava.com/) to receive requests from your Android app and send responses back to your Android app. On your Android device, you would make an HTTP request to your Heroku instance (which will be at some URL), you will use Spark running in Heroku to receive the request, you will mint a custom token using Firebase Admin, and then you can send the custom token back to your Android device as a Spark response.

Answer (score 3):

Typically, you create custom tokens when you're handling the user authentication by yourself. Then we can envision the following information flow:

1. Android app sends user credentials (e.g. username and password) to your backend server in Heroku.
2. The backend server authenticates the user, and creates a custom token (the code you have at the moment).
3. The custom token is sent back to the Android app as the authentication response.

Now you can use the custom token in Android app to authenticate with Firebase.

Hope this clears things up.